# Best way to add query param to all navigations

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

I am looking for a solution to add query param on each URL after navigation using WebDriverIO.

For example:
Base URL: `https://www.google.com/?block=true`

When I click a button on the page loaded from the above URL, new URL that loads is `https://www.google.com/search-page`.

I would like to append `?block=true` to all the navigations.

For the base URL, I can use the method `browser.url("https://www.google.com/?block=true")`. Not sure how I can add to other pages that are navigated using click actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to generate complex search params. Check out the below example.

```js
const baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/?block=true"; // window.location.href
const searchUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?test=testparam";

function getRedirectUrl(baseUrl, newUrl) {
  let oldParms = new URL(baseUrl).searchParams;
  const newUrlParams = new URL(newUrl).searchParams;
  for(let [value, key] of oldParms.entries()){
    newUrlParams.append(key, value);
  }
  const newSearch = new URL(newUrl).search;
  return `${newUrl.slice(0, -1 * newSearch.length)}?${newUrlParams.toString()}`;
}

console.log(getRedirectUrl(baseUrl, searchUrl));
```